# Differences in Model Fit Evaluation Between Exploratory Factor Analysis and Confirmatory Factor Analysis

Tags: factor-analysis, model-evaluation, structural-equation-modeling, confirmatory-factor, exploratory-data-analysis

For the same dataset, I tried both exploratory factor analysis (EFA) and confirmatory factor analysis (CFA). For evaluating EFA model, the cumulative explanation of all latent factors adds up to around 25% (I know it's a poor fit). Then I tried CFA with one particular latent factor hypothesis, the measurements for model fit are BIC, AIC, RMSEA. There is no cumulative explanation score given by the CFA package, so I calculated it manually. However, I got 44% which is higher than the 25% I got in the EFA model. I'm now confused and have a few questions.

1. Should EFA models and CFA models be evaluated by different types of measurements? What's the point of evaluating EFA with the cumulative explainaition while evaluating CFA with BIC, AIC, and RMSEA?
2. I thought EFA gives me the best fitted model from a data driven perspective, so that the model fit score (cumulative explaination) would be higher than any theory driven CFA models. However, my CFA model has a higher cumulative explaination score (44%) than EFA (25%). Do people have any thoughts on this? It could be that I calculated mine CFA score wrong, but could anyone tell me how to calculate cumulative latent factor explanation scores in EFA?

Thank you!

Just to clarify, by saying "cumulative explanation", I meant the cumulated variance explained by all latent factors. In exploratory factor analysis, there is usually a table output that looks like this:

[image]

The third column third row in the table shows that about 44% of the variance is explained by three factors.

Comment: What do you mean by "cumulative explanation"? And how did you calculate this in CFA? Did you fit a single factor model (In CFA) and extract a single factor (in EFA)?

Comment: Cumulative shows the percentage of variance explained by n+(n1) factors. For example, factor 1 and factor 2 account for 57.55% of the total variance. The last table in this post https://medium.com/@hongwy1128/intro-guide-to-factor-analysis-python-84dd0b0fd729 is an example of cumulative variance. Previously, I used "cov.values.diagonal().sum()" to calculate cumulative variance for CFA model based on covariance matrix, but I doubt if it's the correct way because the output value is higher than EFA model.

Comment: And I fit my CFA model with 3 latent factors, each has 2-3 indicators; the EFA model is totally data-driven and the final model has 3 factors (1 indicator in the first 2 factors and 2 indicators in the last factor). I hope it clarifies your question. Please let me know if you have any suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not familiar with "cov.values.diagonal().sum()". That's Python? (If that's what I think it is) it's not usually calculated in CFA, because you're not trying to explain the maximum variance in CFA, you're trying to get the right model (in the same way that R^2 is secondary in SEM, but more commonly reported in regression).

Comment: Yes. The code is written in python. I think what you said answers my question. Thanks!